# How to change radius of segmented control in swiftUI without using old UISegmentControl

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, swiftui

I was trying to change radius of segment control in SwiftUI. I am only able to change the outer radius. Is there any way to change the radius of selected tag?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var favoriteColor = 0
    var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $favoriteColor, label: Text("What is your favorite color?")) {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count) { index in
                    Text(self.colors[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
             .cornerRadius(13). ////////////////////////////////--

            Text("Value: \(colors[favoriteColor])")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I upvoted, I have two requests. (1) Could you post enough code to duplicate your issue? It would help. (2) Can you *clearly* define what you mean by *"...change radius of the selected tag..." Let's stick with the old - `UIKit` - can you show me something that is different between what you want and what `SwiftUI` does with the "selected tag"?

Answer (score 3):

At this point, I believe there is no way to modify the properties (e.g. shape) of the selected tag. I assume this is either a stylistic choice by Apple (because they want standard controls to truly look "standard"), or they just haven't gotten around to it (SwiftUI is very much a 1.0 at this point).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Introspection Library](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to access the underlying `UISegmentedControl` from the SwiftUI view. Doing so, you can customize it. Here's an example for you:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    // 1.
    @State private var selectorIndex = 0
    @State private var numbers = ["One","Two","Three"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // 2
            Picker("Numbers", selection: $selectorIndex) {
                ForEach(0 ..< numbers.count) { index in
                    Text(self.numbers[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            .introspectSegmentedControl{
                segmentedControl in

                segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 170.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 170.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
                segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                segmentedControl.layer.masksToBounds = true
                segmentedControl.clipsToBounds = true
            }

            // 3.
            Text("Selected value is: \(numbers[selectorIndex])").padding()
        }
    }
}
```